# Huge CPU time difference between multiple processes when listening on the same socket

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tornado, httpserver

I'm running a tornado http server on a 8-core ec2 instance(ubuntu 14.04, kernel=3.13), preforking 16 processes. In the frontend, there is a nginx proxying requests to the tornado server.

There are 120 incoming requests per second.

A `ps aux | grep python` indicates that some processes' CPU time are way higher than others:

```
root  5097  0.0  0.2 186224 33740 ?    SNs  Dec21   0:00 python src/app/server.py
root  5157  0.0  0.2 497556 37212 ?    SNl  Dec21   1:58 python src/app/server.py
root  5158  0.0  0.2 497808 37364 ?    SNl  Dec21   1:51 python src/app/server.py
root  5159  0.5  0.2 501312 41152 ?    SNl  Dec21  22:17 python src/app/server.py
root  5160  0.1  0.2 498876 38716 ?    SNl  Dec21   5:03 python src/app/server.py
root  5161  0.0  0.2 497688 37232 ?    SNl  Dec21   2:14 python src/app/server.py
root  5162  0.0  0.2 499104 38808 ?    SNl  Dec21   2:49 python src/app/server.py
root  5163  0.0  0.2 498328 38004 ?    SNl  Dec21   3:36 python src/app/server.py
root  5164 11.6  0.3 512692 52432 ?    SNl  Dec21 471:59 python src/app/server.py
root  5165  0.1  0.2 498224 37996 ?    SNl  Dec21   4:11 python src/app/server.py
root  5166  0.2  0.2 499700 39440 ?    SNl  Dec21   9:45 python src/app/server.py
root  5167  0.1  0.2 498936 38780 ?    SNl  Dec21   6:36 python src/app/server.py
root  5168  0.0  0.2 498364 38052 ?    SNl  Dec21   3:09 python src/app/server.py
root  5169  1.5  0.2 504196 44048 ?    SNl  Dec21  64:47 python src/app/server.py
root  5170  0.3  0.2 500492 40156 ?    SNl  Dec21  13:53 python src/app/server.py
root  5171  0.0  0.2 498600 38264 ?    SNl  Dec21   2:30 python src/app/server.py
root  5172  5.4  0.3 508692 48388 ?    SNl  Dec21 222:58 python src/app/server.py
```

Although different type of requests have different cpu cost, but it's much more than I expected.

Also, cpu1 seems to be always busier than other cores:

```
%Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.7 ni, 99.0 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.3 us,  1.3 sy,  8.3 ni, 89.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  3.0 ni, 97.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  4.0 ni, 95.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu4  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu5  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.3 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  1.3 ni, 98.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.3 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

But when performing pressure tests using `ab`, The log indicates that requests are basically equally distributed to those processes.

The code:

```
app = tornado.web.Application(routers)
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
socks = tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(8000, '0.0.0.0')
tornado.process.fork_processes(16)
server.add_sockets(socks)
io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
io_loop.start()
```

What could be the cause of such huge difference?

Comment: in your sample logging, `%cpu1` is the lowest utilized. All others look to be well utilized. Are you sure congestion is not occurring elsewhere in your system? There is much code for people to work with here. This Q is probably better posted to a `tornado` specific user group forum. Good luck.

Comment: Actually I'm seeing this happening in several tornado servers running different application. I thought there might be something to do with SO_REUSEPORT, but enabling it didn't make any difference, And you are right. I should post to the tornado user group. Thanks.

Comment: what about response latency? I guess the request rate is not high enough to fully utilize one core / process.

Answer (score 0):

The default sharing of a listening socket across multiple processes doesn't do a great job of load balancing, although it tends to even out when it matters under heavy load (as you see when `ab` distributes its requests across all processes).

Using `SO_REUSEPORT` and binding the sockets *after* the fork can help even out the load. Using a separate load balancer (such as `haproxy` or `nginx`) is the best way to ensure well-balanced load.